# Is there a way to name columns in an INSERT statement?

Tags: mysql, syntax, insert

When I do SELECT statements in PHP code I always select named columns, like:

```
SELECT id, name from users;
```

rather than using:

```
SELECT * from users;
```

This has the advantage of being more informative and readable, and also avoids problems later if new columns are added to the table.

What I'm wondering is, is it possible to use the same idea in an INSERT statement? I'm imagining it might be something like this:

```
INSERT into people values (id=1, name="Fred");
```

The syntax as I've shown in this example doesn't work, but I wonder if something equivalent is possible? If not, does anyone know why not? Is it a deliberate omission?

Comment: Wow! I've been wanting to do this for ages, and it turns out that it was easy, and that pretty much everyone else apart from me already knew about it. I love Stackoverflow...

Comment: If you have another SQL Question, look here http://sqlzoo.net/ . It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's syntax is possible with MySQL only.  Afaik, other RDBMS doesn't allow that.  Here's the syntax:

```
INSERT INTO games SET yr = 2012, city = 'London';
```

I wish PostgreSQL facilitated this kind of insert syntax

Standard ANSI syntax, however, would be

INSERT into people (yr, city) values (2012, 'London');

Comment: The other method, however, is standard SQL, and portable to any standard-compliant RDBMS.

Comment: @Harper: That is an important point, but for me the MySQL-only version is fine, as I'm not writing production software, just stuff for doing things for me, and I'm only ever going to use MySQL... I think... :-)

Comment: You're going to be kicking yourself some time in the future for not doing it the standard SQL way.

Comment: It unportable and I can not see the gains in any way.

Comment: Even PostgreSQL team consider that kind of syntax, it is more readable.  I can't believe that I answer the question in good faith, no malicious intent or whatsoever, yet I received downvote.  Well.. that's life... here.

Comment: @Michael Buen: I agree with you. I personally think your answer was a good answer. I was looking for a MySQL solution, and in my view the answer you proposed is more readable than the more standard one. It's a shame you were downvoted.

Comment: I guess this answer is receiving broken window syndrome. I just hoped in some future time, many RDBMS vendors would consider this syntax more easy to follow than the standard one. That the variable and its value should of closed proximity with each other.

Answer (score 28):

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)

INSERT INTO people (id, name)
VALUES (1, 'Fred');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
INSERT into people(id,name) values (1, 'Fred');
```

Comment: this is correct, except you want single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: Thanks, I cut and pasted and didn't fix that part.  Plus jmien beat me to it by about 10 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

what you want is

```
INSERT INTO PEOPLE ( id, name ) VALUES ( 1, 'FRED' )
```

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO table (column_1, column_2, column_3, ...)
VALUES (value_1, value_2, value_3, ...)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `INSERT INTO <table> (col1, col2) VALUES (1,2)`.

Answer (score 3):

Try it this way:
INSERT INTO people (id, name) VALUES (1, "Fred");

Answer (score 3):

the syntax for this case is

> INSERT into people (id, name) values (1, 'Fred');

at least it works  in the dbms i use (PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 2):

Using standard syntax, you can insert multiple rows at once:

```
INSERT INTO Table (column1,...,columnN) VALUES
(r1v1, ..., r1vN),
(r2v1, ..., r2vN),
(r3v1, ..., r3vN).
```

This is [*MUCH* faster way of importing data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html), than one-row-a-time (especially in MySQL)! I don't think you can do the same using

```
INSERT INTO Table SET column1 = r1v1, ..., columnN = r1vN
```

syntax.

(From personal experience, inserting 300000 rows one row a time took several minutes. When I changed the script to use few insert statements only, each inserting several thousands of rows, it took only few seconds to import it all, MySQL 5.0).